# How to save taxonomy term meta?

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy

Since, WordPress don't have taxonomy metadata support for saving taxonomy custom form fields, I am currently thinking of using options API. But the 1MB options size limit on Wordpress.com is what's troubling me. Originally, I had thought of adding an option say 'my_plugin_term_meta', which will then have term meta indexed by the term taxonomy id(not to be confused with term id).

But, since, this gives rise to scalability issues, I am now thinking of saving term meta in multiple options as 'my_plugin_term_meta_{$tt_id}'. However, I am worried that on larger sites with lots of terms, this will pollute the options table.

So, here I am asking how should I save the taxonomy term meta, considering, I don't want to use wp large options(don't want add any extra dependency) and custom table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of [WordPress 4.4](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.4), Taxonomy term meta is now a part of WordPress.

You can use the following new functions to manage term meta:

- [add_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_term_meta/)
- [update_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_term_meta/)
- [get_term_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)